# What will be the price for BCC bitcoin cash on August 1st?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash

Will there be an "initial price of a chain fork" type of opening when this new BCC comes out? Or the price will be same to the regular BTC that we currently use?

Comment: If you rename this question to be about how an initial price of a chain fork is determined, it becomes a much better question.  Without that change, this is borderline off topic speculation.

Answer (score 2):

The initial price of BCC will be what the first buyer is willing to pay for it on an exchange. After that, it's simply a matter of demand and supply.

According to [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin-cash/), BCC futures are currently trading for $332. This is probably the best indication of what to expect once the market opens.

Comment: I would look at the volume in those futures.